# How to convert UTF-8 list to String in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

i need to save BeautifulSoup results to `.txt` file. and i need convert results to string with `str()` and not worked because list is UTF-8 :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

page_content = soup(page.content, "lxml")

links = page_content.select('h3', class_="LC20lb")

for link in links:
    with open("results.txt", 'a') as file:
        file.write(str(link) + "\n")
```

and get this error :

```
  File "C:\Users\omido\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 183-186: character maps to <undefined>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write to the file as UTF-8 as well, you’ll need to specify that:

```
with open("results.txt", 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(str(link) + "\n")
```

and it’s a good idea to only open the file once:

```
with open("results.txt", 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for link in links:
        file.write(str(link) + "\n")
```

(You can also `print(link, file=file)`.)